# How to find out the default file manager in the terminal?

Tags: desktop-environment, file-manager

I'm working on different Linux distributions.

In my `.bashrc` I'd like to set up an alias that opens a window of the default file manager (e.g. `nautilus`, `nemo`, `pacman`, ...).

Is there a way find out what the file-manager of a session is? (It does also depends on the session, doesn't it?)

Comment: `xdg-open .` works in all desktop environments using the default file manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As comments have already stated, you're probably better off with `xdg-open` (no alias needed), but to answer the question: You can use `xdg-mime` to query and set default applications. To get the default file manager:

`xdg-mime query default inode/directory`

Read more about this topic in the [xdg-mime manual](https://portland.freedesktop.org/doc/xdg-mime.html) or the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications).

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't.

Or at least there's no simple magic command for guessing what's the current desktop's default file manager.

All what `xdg-open` or `xdg-mime query` will do or tell you, is what has been associated to the desktop object type "folder" (inode/directory type), for the action "open". This is neither what defines a file manager in general, nor what defines what's the desktop's default one or what you expect.

What is associated to the inode/directory type could be whatever application you've installed that associates itself to directories (audacious does it - is that the file manager you'd expect? it's not the only one).

Comment: KDE even calls the setting `default applications -> file manager`. It is safe to assume that next to no one would choose audacious as default file manager. I've flagged your answer, as it is kind of opposite to a constructive answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The tool associated with the action "open" for directories _is_ the default file manager. That is precisely how it is defined, how else? If the user has changed the default, then that is what they want to open. It's the same mechanism that decides what to do if a user double clicks on a directory on their Window Manager's desktop.